# Does SQL has some standard data-time function cross database?

Tags: sql

Does SQL has some standard data-time function cross database? Such as :

- extract year, month, day, hour, minute or second
- format to specific formatter
- parse from string

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answers are yes, no, and no.

The extraction functions are `extract(<whatever> from date)`.  I don't think there is a standard for parsing and formatting.  However, `to_char()` and `to_date()` are used across multiple databases.